# Calculate partial derivatives $f_x(x,y)$ and $f_y(x,y)$ if $f(x,y)=\int_{\int_y^xg(t)dt}^{\int_x^yg(t)dt}g(t)dt$

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Calculate partial derivatives $f_x(x,y)$ and $f_y(x,y)$ if $f(x,y)=\int_{\int_y^xg(t)dt}^{\int_x^yg(t)dt}g(t)dt$

Idea: if $G'(t)=g(t)$ for all $t$. Then $\int_y^xg(t)dt= G(x)-G(y)$ and $\int_x^yg(t)dt=G(y)-G(x)$. Hence $f(x,y)=\int_{\int_y^xg(t)dt}^{\int_x^yg(t)dt}g(t)dt=\int_{G(x)-G(y)}^{G(y)-G(x)}g(t)dt=G(G(y)-G(x))-G(G(x)-G(y))$.

Then

$f_x(x,y)=-G'(G(y)-G(x))G'(x)-G'(G(x)-G(y))G'(x)=-g(x)(g(\int_x^yg(t)dt)+g(\int_y^xg(t)dt))?$

Is correct my idea?

Thanks...

Comment: I found the implied recursiveness interesting and created a follow up question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3374896/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to the rescue:

$$\frac{d}{d x}\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x, t) d t\right)=f(x, b(x)) \cdot \frac{d}{d x} b(x)-f(x, a(x)) \cdot \frac{d}{d x} a(x)+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x, t) d t$$

Applying this formula to $I=I(x, y)=\int_x^y g(t) dt$ yields $\frac{d}{d x} I(x, y) = - g(x)$ and $\frac{d}{d y} I(x, y) = g(y)$.

Now, using $I(y,x)=-I(x,y)$ we can apply the rule a second time to the integral we are interested in:

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{d x}\left(\int_{-I(x,y)}^{I(x,y)} g(t) d t\right)
&= g(I)\frac{d}{d x}I(x, y) - g(-I)\frac{d}{d x}(-I(x,y)) \\
&=-g(x)\big(g(I)+g(-I)\big)
\end{aligned}$$

which agrees with your result. In fact, your idea can be used to actually proof Leibniz's formula.

If we like to we can also use recursiveness of the problem and the chain rule

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{d x}\left(\int_{-I(x,y)}^{I(x,y)} g(t) d t\right)
&= \frac{d}{d x}I(-I(x,y), I(x,y)) = (-g(-I), g(I))  \cdot (g(x), -g(x))\\
&= -g(x)\big(g(I)+g(-I)\big)
\end{aligned}$$