# Recursive integrals a la $\int_{\int_y^xg(t)dt}^{\int_x^yg(t)dt}g(t)dt$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3374748/calculate-partial-derivatives-f-xx-y-and-f-yx-y-if-fx-y-int-int-y)
I was wondering whether "recursive" integrals have been studied or if they appear anywhere in applications. What I mean is the following: Let $I(x, y) = \int_x^y g(t) dt$ and define

$$\begin{aligned}
I_0 &= \int_x^y g(t) dt &&= I(x, y)\\
I_1 &=   \int_{\int_y^xg(t)dt}^{\int_x^yg(t)dt}g(t) dt &&= I(-I(x,y), +I(x, y)) \\
I_2 &= \int_{\int^{\int_y^xg(t)dt}_{\int_x^yg(t)dt}g(t) dt}^{\int_{\int_y^xg(t)dt}^{\int_x^yg(t)dt}g(t) dt} g(t) dt
&&=I(-I(-I, +I), +I(-I, +I)) \\
&&\vdots \\
I_{n+1} &= I(-I_n, +I_n)
\end{aligned}$$

What can be said about convergence criteria for this process? It should be straight-forward to show that for non-negative functions a blow up happens if $\int^x g(t) dt$ grows asymptotically faster than $x$. Otherwise it should converge I think. But who knows what could happen when fast oscillating functions taking both positive and negative values are involved.

Comment: Let $F(u) = \int_{-u}^u g(t)\,dt$.  Then you ask about the iterates of $F$; a subject with vast literature.  So, how does the assertion that $F(u) = \int_{-u}^u g(t)\,dt$ for some $g$ restrict the choice of the function $F$?

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$z_0 = \int\limits_x^y g(t)\,\text dt,\quad F(z)=\int\limits_{-z}^z g(t)\,\text dt.$$

Then we have a simple iteration
$$z_{i+1}=F(z_i),$$
with the sufficient condition of convergency in the form of
$$|F(z)|<\gamma|z|,\qquad(|z|\le|z_0|)$$
where $\;\gamma<1.\;$

Comment: very nice answer. trivial but nice